# Split list values inside dictionary to separate dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I have the following json response from a flask application and am wondering how I can split it out into multiple "rows"/dicts.

Output:

```
{'class': [0.0, 1.0],
 'probability': [0.8488858872836712, 0.1511141127163287]}
```

What I desire is:

```
[{"class": 0.0, "probability": 0.8488858872836712},{"class": 1.0, "probability": 0.1511141127163287}]
```

I've tried something like the following but am not sure how to get both keys:

```
{k: v for e in zip(model.classes_, probabilities[0]) for k, v in zip(('class', 'probability'), e)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more generic solution (if you do not know the key names ahead of time):

```
d = {'class': [0.0, 1.0], 'probability': [0.8488858872836712, 0.1511141127163287]}
result = [dict(zip(d.keys(), i)) for i in zip(*d.values())]
```

Output:

```
[{'class': 0.0, 'probability': 0.8488858872836712}, {'class': 1.0, 'probability': 0.1511141127163287}]
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was thinking about doing something like that but I just don't have the skill yet. :-)

Comment: @accdias Thank you. Your solution is fine as well, if the OP does indeed know the key names ahead of time, then simple `zip` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the output stored in `d`, you can do

```
[{'class': c, 'probability': p} for c,p in zip(d['class'], d['probability'])]
```

That will result in:

```
[{'class': 0.0, 'probability': 0.8488858872836712},
 {'class': 1.0, 'probability': 0.1511141127163287}]
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d={'class': [0.0, 1.0],
...  'probability': [0.8488858872836712, 0.1511141127163287]}
>>> pprint([{'class': c, 'probability': p} for c,p in zip(d['class'], d['probability'])])
[{'class': 0.0, 'probability': 0.8488858872836712},
 {'class': 1.0, 'probability': 0.1511141127163287}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Split json using list comprehension

```
dic = { 'class': [0.0, 1.0], 'probability': [0.8488858872836712, 0.1511141127163287] }

split_value = [{'class':i,'probability':j} for i,j in zip(dic['class'],dic['probability'])]

print(split_value)
```

Output:-

```
[{'class': 0.0, 'probability': 0.8488858872836712}, {'class': 1.0, 'probability': 0.1511141127163287}]
```