# How to expand a list of strings within dictionary to produce list of dictionaries while retaining key?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, zip, key

I have come across several approaches but none seem to fit what I am trying to do. To keep it simple, I have a dictionary with >20k keys and each key has a list of strings (lists of different lengths). I am simply trying to take each string within the list of each key and generate of the list of dictionaries before the function does calculations within each individual dictionary.

```
pep_dic={gene1:[str1,str2,str3], gene2:[str1,str2], etc.}
```

This code is part of a bigger function, essentially pep_dict is a dictionary that contains a key with a list of strings. The output I am getting here is an empty list.

```
raw=df[[target, identifier]].set_index(identifier).to_dict()[target]
pep_dict = {}
pep_dic_list = []
for gene,peptide in raw.items():
    pep_dict[gene] = list(parser.cleave(peptide,rule=rule,min_length=min_length,exception=exception,missed_cleavages=missed))
pep_dic_list = [dict(zip(pep_dict.keys(), i)) for i in zip(*pep_dict.values())]
return pep_dic_list
```

**expected output:**

```
pep_dict_list=[{gene1:str1},{gene1:str2},...{gene2:str1},etc.]
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you should do fewer things per line to not confuse yourself and help you better understand what happens. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Not an [mre] and missing data. [edit] and fix please.

Comment: Okay, there is a basic example. some keys have 100s of strings in each list. I am able to make a list of dictionaries with the strings but I can't seem to retain the keys. I do not work with dictionaries that much, so just a basic understanding of how to unpack a list using dict.items() would be helpful.

Comment: I have tried a key, value loop as I did with the raw dictionary, but it keeps crashing my computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703305/split-list-values-inside-dictionary-to-separate-dictionaries   this is one example that is similar to what I want but doesn't appear to fit with my dictionary.

Comment: the real problem seem to lie with pep_dic_list = [dict(zip(pep_dict.keys(), i)) for i in zip(*pep_dict.values())]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple loop through nested dictionary using `for` loop.

```
 pep_dic={'gene1':['str1','str2','str3'], 'gene2':['str1','str2']}
    pep_dic_list = []
    
    for k, lst in pep_dic.items():    
        d = {}
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            d.update({k: lst[i]})
            new_d = d.copy()
            pep_dic_list.append(new_d)
    
    
    print(pep_dic_list)

#[{'gene1': 'str1'}, {'gene1': 'str2'}, {'gene1': 'str3'}, {'gene2': 'str1'}, {'gene2': 'str2'}]
```

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't far off with some of my previous attempts, but I didn't think about using a range loop to iterate over the nested list. This makes sense, although I am sure there is a more "pythonic" way.... either way, this gives me a better understanding of how to manipulate dictionaries. Thanks!